# Grub2 is showing filesystem type instead of partition content

Tags: grub2

I tried to list partition with `ls (hd1,gpt7)` command and I got `filesystem is btrfs` output instead of partition content. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you do `insmod btrfs`? You need to load the btrfs module first.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I have to add slash after partition identifier - e.g. `ls (hd1,gpt7)/`